# Tour link redirect to diffrent page

Tags: support, bug, meta

[Tour link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour) redirected to help page instead of **tour page** in meta *help* drop down.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is no longer an issue? The Tour and Help Center have separate links in that dropdown, and both seem to work fine now.